# What is a good mat system for home MMA training?

Tags: training, recommendation, equipment

I practice in WCMA and BJJ, which means I can spend a fair amount of time on the ground working on flows, take downs, clinches, locks, etc. I've been looking around for a decent mat system that I can put in the garage that would allow me and my wife and/or friends, to practice at home.

It's important that that it won't separate or move easily and that it provides some form of padding without causing other issues, i.e. carpet burn.

So I'm wondering if there are any recommendations out there from the community on mat systems, or DIY systems, that I can put in to facility at home training. I'm willing to take any suggestions, but cost is a factor, can't really afford more then a few hundred.

Comment: Curious: WCMA is... Williams College of Modern Art? Wood Components Manufacturers Association? Wisconsin Cheese Makers Association? May want to clarify that... World Class Martial Arts is still like 4 pages down on google for WCMA (I'm assuming that's what you're talking about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various versions of the rubber jigsaw mats that are pretty good, I've trained on a number and have had them for home.  They are not cheap cheap, but also not that expensive.  But there are options, it gets more pricey the thicker you get them.  Any thickness is pretty good for purely grappling.

For throwing / takedowns then the thicker the better really.

Comment: Any particular brand that you would recommend?

Comment: I used https://www.amas.co.nz/custom.cfm?&action=order&categoryid=8&subcatid=43&itemid=567   but they seem "no brand" ish

Comment: also been at a couple of different dojos that use similar but not quite the same rubber interlocking mats, also quite good.   But then maybe I'm not that fussy :)

Comment: I tried some mats that looked like those, but they were more of weight mats by Golds Gym and it turned me off of them. They kept separating on me while doing flows. I will have to take a look at those again and ensure they are good for martial arts activities.

Comment: the only issue I ever had was my toe nail go caught in a gap a few times and it was a bit ouchy, but I should of cut my nails :)

Answer (score -1):

If you like the Gracie style mats, they have a DIY tube so you can create your own.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehb7tfvrXe8

Comment: As videos can be taken down or otherwise become unavailable, this answer would be greatly improved by including a summary of the Gracie mat DIY method.

Answer (score -3):

"www.fujimats.com" I recommend anything 1.5" and above. "fujisports.com/judo/mats-pads/fuji-mats-smooth-series.html" The product is tailored more towards BJJ though they have a few other Mat styles and types for other MAs. Hope this helped!

Comment: Why is this a decent product? Currently, your answer reads like a bad spam post.